# Extracting elements counting 0 in a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

This the dataframe code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    storage = pd.DataFrame({'red_wire':[2,2,8,1,5],'white_wire':[5,5,3,5,2],'black_wire':[0,10,4,2,1]})
```

And the dataframe structure with data:

```
            red_wire  white_wire  black_wire
    0         2           5           0
    1         2           5          10
    2         8           3           4
    3         1           5           2
    4         5           2           1
```

Consider we have two dictionaries. They have tags outside with the color of the wires that must be inside the box:

```
    box1 = {'red_wire':2,'white_wire':5,'black_wire':10}
    box2 = {'red_wire':2,'white_wire':5,'black_wire':0}
```

I made this code to print the boxes contents, my intention is to control and print the wire codes, some boxes may have distinct color tags.
That's why I came out with this code:

```
    for key,value in box1.items():  #getting box tags and quantities

        col_name = [column for column in storage.columns if key == column] #columns in storage df

        for x,i in zip(storage.columns,storage.index): #accesing data in dataframe

            if x in col_name and value:

                print(x,col_name,value)
```

The output is :

```
red_wire ['red_wire'] 2
white_wire ['white_wire'] 5
black_wire ['black_wire'] 10
```

calling the box2:

```
for key,value in box2.items():

    col_name = [column for column in storage.columns if key == column]#columns in dict  

    for x,i in zip(storage.columns,storage.index):#accesing data in dataframe

        if x in col_name and value:

            print(x,col_name,value)

red_wire ['red_wire'] 2
white_wire ['white_wire'] 5
```

In box2 I was expecting to get black_wire ['black_wire'] 0, but it assumes it is a value to skip.
I want to get the prints of the 0 articles in the dictionary evaluation and only skip values if the tag is not present on the box.

Some users provided me good solutions to get the 0 with the 'is not None' after the conditional sentence:

```
 if x in col_name and value is not None:
```

It prints:

```
    red_wire ['red_wire'] 2
    white_wire ['white_wire'] 5
    black_wire ['black_wire'] 0
```

But what if I ask specifically by 0:

```
for key,value in box2.items():

col_name = [column for column in storage.columns if key == column]#columns in dict  

for x,i in zip(storage.columns,storage.index):#accesing data in dataframe

    if x in col_name and value == storage[x][i]:

            print(x,col_name,value)
```

It prints:

```
red_wire ['red_wire'] 2
white_wire ['white_wire'] 5
```

"is not None", doesn't make any difference

```
#is not None 1st
if x in col_name and value is not None and value == storage[x][i]:
            print(x,col_name,value)


red_wire ['red_wire'] 2
white_wire ['white_wire'] 5

#is not None after
if x in col_name and value == storage[x][i] and value is not None:

            print(x,col_name,value)


red_wire ['red_wire'] 2
white_wire ['white_wire'] 5
```

Comment: `value is not None` --> `if x in col_name and value is not None`

Comment: `bool(0) -> False` so `x in col_name and value` is `False` when `value == 0`.

Comment: Zero is a mathematical value. But variables in computer programs are not. Your title suggests that you feel entitled to expect mathematically defined behaviour from a Python variable with the value `0`. You're not. You're only entitled to expect the behaviour defined by the language. Computer variables are approximations of ideal mathematical entities and diverge from exact mathematical behaviour in many ways.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I will edit the title.

Comment: @powerPixie Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your source code.

## 0 is a valid value

In your first version, you used `value` in your conditional, and like said in comments, `bool(0) == false`, so you add to specify `is not None` to manage the fact there is a 0 value, and there is NO value at all.

## Columns and values indexes mixing

In your final version, you are iterating on columns, using the Panda indexing system, called `i` in your loop:

> for x,i in zip(storage.columns,storage.index):#accesing data in dataframe

But you use this index to seek the value in corresponding Dataframe:

> value == storage[x][i]

You are lucky it works for `red_wire`, and `white_wire`, and even `black_wire` for the `box1`.

Maybe you want to ensure the value belongs to the corresponding Dataframe part; in which case you can change your source code this way:

> value in storage[x].values

This way you don't need at all to check if value if not None; and you don't need either to iterate in `index`; your source code could be simplified to:

`for x in storage.columns:
    if x in col_name and value in storage[x].values:`

Let me know if it reaches you needs.